# distinguish between functions and classes (functor)

Tags: c++, function, templates, functor

I have both a function and class called GreaterThan.

```
template <typename T>
bool GreaterThan(const T& number)
{
    return number > 100;
}
```

```
template <typename T>
class GreaterThan
{
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        GreaterThan(T x) : value(x) {}
        ~GreaterThan() {}
        
        bool operator()(T& compare)
        {
            return compare > value;
        }
};
```

How can I distinguish betweeen:

1. `std::find_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(),GreaterThan<int>); // error`
2. `std::find_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(),GreaterThan<int>(100));`

and let the compiler know that 1) should call the function?

Comment: Put them in separate namespaces.  `namespace by_function` and `namespace by_class` seem to be appropriate.

Comment: @Eljay, that just says 'change the name of one of them'

Comment: Just give them unique names

Comment: @pm sure, but it is the easiest solution. Why make it any harder? ;)

Comment: Why not simply name them differently?

Comment: @ Jerry Coffinn you are correct! Just edited question

Comment: What C++ compiler allows a function template and a class template to have the same name in the same namespace?

Comment: @DrewDormann that was my question.  I was wondering if there is a way to have functions and a classes with the same name and some how let the compiler know to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @quant: The short answer is no. Distinguishing between them is irrelevant, because they aren't allowed to exist in the first place.

Comment: _"I have both a function and class called GreaterThan."_  This seems to contradict your comment that you are wondering if it's possible to have this.

Answer (score 6):

From the C++20 Standard (13 Templates)

> 7 **A class template shall not have the same name as any other
> template, class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator,
> namespace, or type in the same scope** (6.4), except as specified in
> 13.7.6. Except that a function template can be overloaded either by non-template functions (9.3.4.6) with the same name or by other
> function templates with the same name (13.10.4), a template name
> declared in namespace scope or in class scope shall be unique in that
> scope.

So your code is invalid because the class template has the same name as the function template.

If the templates are declared in different namespaces then use qualified names.

Here is a demonstration program,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace N1
{
    template <typename T>
    bool GreaterThan( const T &number )
    {
        return number > 3;
    }
}

namespace N2
{
    template <typename T>
    class GreaterThan
    {
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        GreaterThan( const T &x ) : value( x ) {}
        ~GreaterThan() {}

        bool operator()( const T &compare ) const
        {
            return compare > value;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto it1 = std::find_if( v1.begin(), v1.end(), N1::GreaterThan<int> );  
    auto it2 = std::find_if( v1.begin(), v1.end(), N2::GreaterThan<int>( 3 ) );

    if ( it1 != v1.end() ) std::cout << "*it1 = " << *it1 << '\n';
    if ( it2 != v1.end() ) std::cout << "*it2 = " << *it2 << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
*it1 = 4
*it2 = 4
```

If you are using non-template class and function in the same scope then for an object of the class type use elaborated type specifier. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool GreaterThan( const int &number )
{
    return number > 3;
}

class GreaterThan
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    GreaterThan( const int &x ) : value( x ) {}

    bool operator()( const int  &compare ) const 
    {
        return compare > value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto it1 = std::find_if( v1.begin(), v1.end(), GreaterThan );   
    auto it2 = std::find_if( v1.begin(), v1.end(), class GreaterThan( 3 ) );

    if ( it1 != v1.end() ) std::cout << "*it1 = " << *it1 << '\n';
    if ( it2 != v1.end() ) std::cout << "*it2 = " << *it2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The relevant quote is not specific to C++20 - identical wording is in every C++ standard to date (as I write this - I have no crystal ball that can predict how the standard will evolve in future).  Only difference is that the containing section and para numbers, and cross-referencing vary between standards (e.g. in C++ 89/90, the quote is in Section 14 "Templates", para 5).

Comment: ADL may provide a way, but that is bad design too. ADL instantiated expression can be wrapped in a lambda.